# Cannot import SearchBar / SearchAnchor components from material3 library

Tags: flutter, android-studio, components, material-design, searchbar

I'm beginner at Flutter development environment. now would like to try out SearchBar/ Searchanchor components at UI screen. I do add  them as the same flow as https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchBar-class.html

Making sure to use

- flutter:
  uses-material-design: true at pubspec.yaml file
- import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  at .dart file
- ThemeData(useMaterial3: true) at MaterialApp

but SearchBar/ Searchanchor classes can't not accessible in .dart file yet.

Comment: `SearchAnchor` is a **widget** which from material package. if u import the package properly u can able to use the widget in your dart file. share your dart code so that we can help you more.